# How to return link to file in ASP Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, static-files, fileprovider

I do not know how to serve links to files in ASP Net Core.I have tried using the `PhyisicalFileProvider` class to no avail.

**What i want**

> Given a folder root on the hard disk , on receiving  a querystring
>   like : `/localFolder/test.txt` i want the server to send a `Link` so
>   the user can click and get the file `test.txt`

**Important**
I **do not** want to send **the file** but a **link** to it , so he can click it and download it.

**What i have tried**:

1.Using the extension method `IApplicationBuilder.Map` in order to direct the requests directly to the file.

2.Using the extension method `IApplicationBuilder.Map` + Adding a middleware ,though i do not know how to i serve the link ? (add it
    in the response body?)

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection collection)
{
      //i have also added the provider to the service collection to further inject it in the middleware 
       var phyisicalFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(config.Storage.DocxFileRoot);
       services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(phyisicalFileProvider);
}
public void Configure()
{
  //scenario without middleware
   app.Map("/localfiles", x => 
         x.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider([some file root]),RequestPath ="/localfiles"}
           ));
   //scenario with middleware 
   app.Map("/localfiles",x=>
               x.UseMiddleware<FileWare>()
          );


   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=File}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });

}
```

**Middleware**

```
public class FileWare
{
      private IFileProvider provider;
      private RequestDelegate next;

      public FileWare(RequestDelegate next,IFileProvider provider)
      { 
           this.provider=provider;
           this.next=next;
      }

      public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
      {
            var query = context.Request.Query;
            var path=query.First(x => x.Key == "path").Value;
            var fileInfo=this.provider.GetFileInfo(path);
            await fileInfo.CreateReadStream().CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);
       }
}
```

Comment: SO, you just want to have a link in razor view.click the link to download a file in the local disk?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a link in razor view,click the link to download a file in the local disk(for example `C:\MyFolder`), you could follow below steps:

1.Razor View

```
<a asp-controller="File" asp-action="download" asp-route-path="C:\MyFolder\test.txt">Download</a>
```

2.FileController

```
public IActionResult Download([FromQuery]string path)
    {

        string fileName = "test.txt";

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        return File(fileBytes, "application/force-download", fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below helps to serve files to users in ASP NET Core:

in **program.cs** write this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "RealFilePath")),
    RequestPath = "/NickNameForPath"
});
```

then in **yourpage.cshtml**, code this link:

```
<a href="~/NickNameForPath/myFile.html" class="html" alt="Serving User Anytime">Get File</a>
```

And do not forget place folders under **wwwroot**